# how to return js object to unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm using the Google Draco decoder to decode mesh the following.

```
var dracoGeometry;
dracoGeometry = new decoderModule.Mesh();
decodingStatus = decoder.DecodeBufferToMesh(buffer, dracoGeometry);
```

when I check the type of the draceGeometrytry:
console.log( typeof dracoGeometry);

I get the

"object" type.

Now my problem is "how can I return this object to unity". What return type supported in C# to accept js object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some methods available, but it doesn't seem possible at the moment to send a mesh from js to unity. If you are working with google draco, I recommend you to follow [this fork](https://gitlab.com/atteneder/DracoUnity)

Answer (score 2):

You can send strings or numbers, so what I would do is create a js object that has the data you need then call `JSON.stringify` on it to convert it to a string then send that over using `unityInstance.SendMessage`:

```js
function sendToUnity(obj) {
    unityInstance.SendMessage('MyGameObject', 'MyMethod', JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

```cs
// in a script attached to a gameobject named "MyGameObject"
void MyMethod(string s) 
{
    Debug.Log(s);
    // decode from json, do stuff with result etc
}
```

As for what you can do with that data while it is in JSON string form, you can use a variety of solutions to decode the JSON string once you have it in Unity. See [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36239705/1092820) for more information.

So if your js looks like this:

```js
function sendToUnity(obj) {
    unityInstance.SendMessage('MyGameObject', 'MyMethod', JSON.stringify(obj));
}

sendToUnity({
    playerId: "8484239823",
    playerLoc: "Powai",
    playerNick:"Random Nick"
});
```

You could do something like this in Unity:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public string playerId;
    public string playerLoc;
    public string playerNick;
} 

...

void MyMethod(string s) 
{
    Player player = JsonUtility.FromJson<Player>(s);
    Debug.Log(player.playerLoc);
}
```

Source: [**Programmer**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/1092820)

Comment: but my object is a kind of mesh. in unity side, its a just byte array, and I want to decode it with js with jslib side. how can I convert it to a string. and then how can create a mesh from the string.

Comment: @badcode try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(dracoGeometry));` and then in C#, writing a `class` that corresponds to the structure you see there.

Comment: it returns {"ptr":12689328}